# Merged Manifest Warning after upgrading Android Studio to 3.2.1

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-manifest

After upgrading to `Android Studio 3.2.1`, when editing the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I see my `<application>` section of the file highlighted in yellow (presumably due to warning below).
I also see a new tab titled `Merged Manifest` which contains the warning :

> Merging Errors: Warning activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launch Mode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present app main manifest (this file), line 23

Questions:

1. Is this new tab something new in AS 3.2.1?  Or is it showing up since AS 3.2.1 is finding a new warning that the previous version did not?
2. What is the warning about?  Do I need to add an activity in my app's AndroidManifest.xml for Firebase for some reason?
3. How do I fix it?

(Note: there was probably a Firebase update as well around the same time.)

Firebase is up-to-date at present.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
```

Everything compiles and runs fine in spite of this.

Comment: Did you find any Solution

Comment: No.  Are you experiencing this as well?

Comment: yup getting same warning

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Firebase (which is where I suspect the problem lies, but it very well may be AS 3.2.1).  If I get a reply with anything useful, I will update this.

Comment: I got a response from Firebase support but they could not reproduce it.  They would like to get an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as can be expected, but right now I do not have the time to create one.  @Vinit, if you are able to do this, feel free to send them one. The case number is [5-4824000024047] for your reference.

Comment: I have the same issue. I wonder would having another Manifest at debug source set be a requirement for reproducing of the issue?

Answer (score 14):

First add the following activity to the application node in the manifest additions:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    tools:replace="android:launchMode" />
```

Then add following to the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
```

Comment: what do you mean about 'the application node in the manifest additions'? Thanks

Comment: <manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: How and where did you found this solution ?

Comment: I've seen the first part elsewhere. Why do you need the second part? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577588/replace-other-declarations-but-no-other-declaration-present#answer-59177027

Answer (score 1):

the issue was introduced with `firebase-auth:16.0.5`...

keeping that dependency at the previous version is a possible workaround:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
}
```

one possibly can ignore that warning, so far noticed no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work putting the following line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //add this line
    ...>
```

and only the following self closing activity tag.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    tools:replace="android:launchMode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was not due to Firebase.

I had created a new launcher icon that I called `my_launcher`. The 2 generated files `my_launcher.xml` and `my_launcher_round.xml` had errors.

For my case, it didn't find `@mipmap/ic_launcher_background` for the `background` tag. I removed it and the rebuild worked.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce issue came if you have package with Uppercase, please re-check your naming package. **to solve this issue make all package name you created to lowercase.**

[image: before]

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt and then type below command

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

Answer (score -5):

Figured out what was causing this !

The whole `<application>...</application>` section was being highlighted because of the warning

[image]

I was able to fix the issue by adding the line

```
<application

      ..

      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"

      ..>
      ..

</application>
```

Alternately, one may want to add a link from a URL - for more info, see [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/8278273/vinit-poojary, hope this helps you.

Comment: this is not a proper solution, u just disable the google indexing warning

Comment: Not everyone needs to do the link, so it is the solution for those people.  Plus, for those who want to do the linking, I provided the link in my answer above on how to do that (enter link description here - url : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing).

Comment: Eventually I did do the app link indexing (see link above) because I wanted that anyway for google indexing.