# Replace other declarations but no other declaration present?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

My AndroidManifest.xml file look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     package="com.example.varianttecnology.uberclone">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"></activity>
</application>
```

And I am useing build.gradle version

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
  }

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
      }
   }
}

  task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

And build.gradle(APP) file look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.varianttecnology.uberclone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
   }
 }

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Add libraries
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But it always show this Warning in AndroidManifest.xml file, how to solve this Warning?

```
E:\Andriod\EdmtDev\Uber 
Clone\UberClone\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:l 
aunchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations 
but no other declaration present
```

Questions:

1. Is this new tab something new in AS 3.2.1? Or is it showing up since AS 3.2.1 is finding a new warning that the previous version did not?
2. What is the warning about?
3. How do I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error/28106780#28106780 by @Kayvan N worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Please try to enter this code in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...>

<activity
    android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
    tools:replace="android:launchMode"
    android:launchMode="standard" />
...
```

Comment: worked for me. Don't forget the first part. I skipped it at first. Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the opening manifest tag at the top of AndroidManifest.xml or you'll get errors about `tools:replace="android:launchMode"`

Answer (score 5):

This issues can be solved by merging the permissions from multiple manifest files with

```
<uses-permission tools:node="merge" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission tools:node="merge" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```