# Having issues Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-espresso

Warning uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:16 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        tools:node="remove" />



here is my buildgradle:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 56
        versionName "1.1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: it is in bottom <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        tools:node="remove" />     remove this

Comment: What is the problem with that?My apps uses location in background.

Comment: click here[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577588/replace-other-declarations-but-no-other-declaration-present]